# jsonschema check if key exists

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I have JSON:

```
{"price" : 12}
```

and schema:

```
schema = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "price" : {"type" : "number"}
    },
}
```

It works to validate the type of value `validate({"price" : 12}, schema)`.
However JSONs like:

```
{"price_blabla" : 'blabla'}
```

are also considered valid. How should I change schema so it would check that a JSON contains the particular keys? Basically I have a lot of JSONs and I need to get all that have a certain pattern.

Comment: Question is answered, but my example may be useful to someone:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76006186/10403806

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In jsonschema there is property called `'required'`, using this field
  we can check whether a JSON contains the particular keys.
- Missing the required field property makes the JSON document invalid.

Sample:

```
schema = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "price" : {"type" : "number"}
    },"required": ["price"]
}

validate({"price_blabla" : 'blabla'}, schema)
```

This will throw the following error.

```
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 'price' is a required property
```

Reference :

> https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#required