# How to specify if a property should not exist or contain null?

Tags: jsonschema

A year ago I've asked [how to set the type of a schema object based on the value of another property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53881623/3094533) which I've got a great answer for, and I've been using that schema ever since.

Now the source data have changed - and the schema is failing under the following circumstances:

The source data contains many properties, however only two of them are relevant for this question: "key" and "value" - the type of "value" depends on the value of "key" -

For instance:
If the key is "comment", the type of value `{"Text":"commentValue"}`.
If the key is "offset", the type of value is `{"seconds":int}`.
If the key is "weather", the type of value is `{"value": Enum["sun", "clouds", "rain"...]}`

Some of the keys do not have the value property, so the schema should forbid it from appearing with these keys - for instance, if the key is "standby" the value property should not appear at all - which is what my current schema is doing good.

However, now the data source have changed and I get `"value" :{}` as a part of my Json where once it was omitted - and the current schema does not allow it.

So my question is - how do I allow one of these two options? I've tried any combination of `anyOf` I could think of, but failed miserably - the `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema` failed to parse the text.

Here's a simplified version of the schema I'm currently using:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "TestOptionalObject",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "test"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/test"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "test": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "key"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "comment",
            "offset",
            "standby",
            "status_unsure",
            "status_ok"
          ]
        }
      },
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "event": {
                "enum": [
                  "standby",
                  "status_unsure",
                  "status_ok"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "value": false
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "key": {
                "const": "comment"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "value": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/commentValue"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "key": {
                "const": "offset"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "value": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/offsetValue"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "commentValue": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [
        "text"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "offsetValue": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [
        "seconds"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "seconds": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int32"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
"then": {
  "properties": {
    "anyOf": [
      { "value": false },
      { "value": null }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
"then": {
  "anyOf": [
  {
    "properties": {
      { "value": false }
    },
    "properties": {
      { "value": null }
    }
  ]  
}
```

```
"then": {
  "properties": {
    "value": 
      "anyOf": [false, null ]
  }
}
```

Json examples to validate:

Should fail:

```
{
  "test": {
    "key": "comment",
      "value": {"seconds":12}
  }
}

{
  "test": {
    "key": "standby",
     "value": {"asdf":12}
  }
}
```

Should pass:

```
{
  "test": {
    "key": "comment",
     "value": {"text":"comment text"}
  }
}


{
  "test": {
    "key": "offset",
     "value": {"seconds":12}
  }
}

{
  "test": {
    "key": "standby"
  }
}

{
  "test": {
    "key": "standby",
     "value": {}
  }
}
```

Note the last example - the `value` property is an empty object - that also should pass but fails with the current schema since the `value` property should not exist at all for this key.

Comment: Not sure about this, but I think the second approach is on the right track. However, instead of `value: null` you want `value: object` with `maxProperties: 0`.

Comment: I'll happily provide you with a solution, but can you provide some example JSON instances you want to validate? Please provide a few examples of both valid and invalid.

Comment: Looks like I answered your previous question too! =D

Comment: @Relequestual Yeah, thanks, that answer serves me to this day well - I'll be happy if you could solve this little problem as well :-) Edited json examples into my question

Comment: I'm pretty confident I know the solution. I'll provide it for you over lunch! =]

Comment: I'm going to assume in your simplified schema, you meant for `event` to be `key`.

Comment: Yes, that assumption is correct. Copy'n'Paste error...

Comment: Question is answered, but my example may be useful to someone:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76006186/10403806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but not quite. You have to remember that the `allOf` is an array of subschemas (JSON Schemas). (Null isn't a valid schema, so you might have got some "not a valid schema" errors.)

As such, consider this modified subschema from `allOf[0]`...

```
{
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "key": {
        "enum": [
          "standby",
          "status_unsure",
          "status_ok"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "value": {
        "type": [
          "object"
        ],
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can test it here: https://jsonschema.dev/s/EfNI1

The `if` block remains the same. *(Although I've corrected what I assume was a mistake in using `event` rather than `key` in your simplification from the real schema.)*

The `then` block needs to define that the object (already checked by `definitions.test`) has a key of `value`, where the value of `value` is an object, and has no properties (aka an empty object).

To achive "an empty object", you need to use `additionalProperties`.

- `additionalProperties` applies its value subschema to all properties that exist that haven't been defined in `properties` or that match the keys (regexes) from `patternProperties`.
- `false` as a schema always fails validation.

`additionalProperties` without `properites` applies to ALL properties, and therefore with a value of false, validates "is an empty object".

Comment: Since 2018 I've set up a "buy me a coffee" page. If you'd like to say thanks beyond an upvote and selecting as accepted answer, you can find the link on my SO profile or the https://jsonschema.dev site.

Comment: Thanks, but I still want to allow `value` to not exist at all (or being an empty object) - That would be `"type":["object", "null"], "additionalProperties": false` - is that correct?

Comment: If it's not included in `required`, then it isn't required. `null` in JSON IS STILL a valid value, and is different to simply omitting the key in the object all together. Make sense?